# How to dynamically add new users on mesos cluster?

Tags: cluster-computing, distributed-computing, mesos

I have a mesos cluster with a master and 6 agents. I have enabled authentication for users and passed user credentials with their roles while starting mesos-master. Now I wanted to dynamically add new users to the master. How can I do that without stopping mesos-master?

Answer (score 0):

You can develop your own authentication module

> Authenticatee and Authenticator modules allow for third parties to quickly develop and plug-in new authentication methods. An example for such modules could be to support PAM (LDAP, MySQL, NIS, UNIX) backed authentication. — [Documentation / Modules](https://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/modules/)

[Here](https://github.com/mesos/modules/tree/master/authentication) you can see example how to do it. This code is quite old but it shows basic concept.